# AWS S3 GetObject error on cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I am the owner of AWS **AccountC** and need List and Get Permissions to **BucketName** owned by another person/team.

The bucket policy created is attached below. Policy for ***AccountA*** and ***AccountB*** were already existing and I added the policy for ***AccountC*** as given below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/ABC-Prod"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AccessB",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:user/service-user",
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:role/BatchUserRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AccessC",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountC:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AccessD",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountC:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to list contents of **BucketName** using
`aws s3 ls BucketName`.

However, when I try
`aws s3 cp --recursive BucketName/folderName/ .`, it gives me an Access Denied error

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied`

Block public access is enabled on the bucket, however I believe it should not affect since the Bucket policy is added

Tried multiple way to write the policy but the error persists. Can someone please help me understand what I might be missing here? Would be really grateful

Comment: Bucket policy doesn't apply to objects owned by another account unless the ACL bucket-owner-full-control is set on the object. I've been bit by this a bunch of times but have never found it clearly documented....

Comment: @jordanm this bucket policy is added to the bucket I need to access in Account C

Comment: What jordanm says is that the bucket policy does not matter if the **objects** in the bucket do not belong to the account that owns the bucket - this only applies if external accounts performed the `PutObject` operations. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/ on how to enforce the bucket owner has access to the objects. The even more frequent cause for AccessDenied is that you do not access to the KMS key that is used to encrypt / decrypt the S3 data - do you have SSE with KMS enabled?

Comment: And you ***really*** need to go through [How do I troubleshoot 403 Access Denied errors from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

Comment: The owner of the bucket confirmed that there is no encryption being used on the data and that other accounts access it

Comment: What permissions does your user have within AccountC, is the user allowed to `s3:GetObject` on `*`?

Comment: Since the permissions are being added to root user, it has all the access within AccountC
```"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountC:root"```

Didn't really understand ```s3:GetObject``` on ```*```

Comment: For cross-account access you need access to s3 both in the source AND in the target account. Additionally to the link I already posted you need to go through [My bucket policy grants full access to another AWS account. Why are IAM users from that account still getting Access Denied errors?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-cross-account-access-denied/) as well, I am pretty sure your issue is solved by going through both links.

Comment: The user availing ```AccessB``` is what actually writes objects to this bucket